# Redis cache InvalidOperationException: Reading is not allowed after reader was completed

Tags: c#, azure, c#-4.0, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have one webjob that is continously inserting data into redis
I have another time trigger function to read data from the same redis cache after every 5 minutes.

```
  public static void ProcessData([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            var newCacheclient = new RedisCacheClient(Program.spRedisCacheConnectionPoolMgr, Program.serializer, Program.redisConfiguration).Db0;

            var cachedData = newCacheclient.GetAsync<List<MyObject>>("mydata").Result;
```

after executing 10-15minutes I'm getting below error from time trigger function .anyone know how to tackle this?

> InvalidOperationException: Reading is not allowed after reader was
> completed.

I raised the same issue with github as well.

nuget version details -
[image]

Error Stack -
Inner Exception 1:

```
InvalidOperationException: Reading is not allowed after reader was completed.


   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at MyData.Functions.ExecuteTrade(TimerInfo myTimer) in C:\Users\\Functions.cs:line 27
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidMethodInvoker`1.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`1.<InvokeAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   
   at System.IO.Pipelines.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_NoReadingAllowed()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.AdvanceReader(SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.AdvanceTo(SequencePosition consumed, SequencePosition examined)
   at StackExchange.Redis.PhysicalConnection.<ReadFromPipe>d__110.MoveNext() in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/PhysicalConnection.cs:line 1495
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core.Implementations.RedisDatabase.<GetAsync>d__14`1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: What is the StackExchange.Redis nuget version you are using? Also please share full stack trace.

Comment: updates question with nuget details pls check thanks

Answer (score 3):

I see couple of problems in the code:

1. You should reuse same redis client instance to avoid ending up with too many tcp connections to redis server.
2. Do not use `.Result` to avoid blocking current thread. Update the method to be async and use await on GetAsync.
3. Make sure you do not store a large object in a cache entry (in this case `List<MyObject>` should not be a large list)

Below is the updated code:

```
        private static readonly IRedisCacheClient redisCacheClient = new RedisCacheClient(Program.spRedisCacheConnectionPoolMgr, Program.serializer, Program.redisConfiguration);
        
        public static async Task ProcessData([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            var redisDB = redisCacheClient.Db0;
            var cachedData = await redisDB.GetAsync<List<MyObject>>("mydata").ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

Comment: thanks i tried using the same but same error i got :( is it better to go with cosmos db instead redis cache to store and retrieve data ?

Comment: Depends on what kind of data. If it has to persisted, then redis is not the right option. If it's for cache on (temporary) then redis is better fit.

Comment: its a stock market data which i'm gathering continously from 9 to 3 from webjob.
and using another function read latest 5 minutes data this is my usecase

Comment: Question is if you are only dealing with recent data or want to maintain it long term. Also, that question of Redis v/s CosmosDB is an architectural question for which StackOverflow is not the right forum https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

You should apply [what @krishg has said first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64367606/3025856). In addition to that, there is a Redis client called `TheUniversalCity.RedisClient` which prevents that error when thousands of `GetAsync` methods are called.

[image: TheUniversalCity.RedisClient vs StackExchange.Redis Benchmark Comparison]

The code block of the `RedisClientParallelCall` method which belongs to TheUniversalCity library that you can see at the benchmark comparison above:

```
[Fact]
[Trait("Category", "RedisClientBenchmark")]
public async Task RedisClientParallelCall()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    var redisClient1 = await RedisClient.CreateClientAsync("localhost,allowAdmin=true,clientCache=false");
    var taskList = new List<Task>();

    sw.Start();

    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(8000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        taskList.Add(redisClient1.GetAsync(TEST_KEY, cts.Token));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
}
```

Here is the code block of the method belongs to the `StackExchange.Redis` library that has the same purpose with the method above:

```
[Fact]
[Trait("Category", "StackExchangeBenchmark")]
public async Task StackExchangeParallelCall()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    var connection = StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost,allowAdmin=true");
    var db = connection.GetDatabase();
    var taskList = new List<Task>();

    sw.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        taskList.Add(db.StringGetAsync(TEST_KEY));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
}
```

I have executed these methods via XUnit Test Provider on Visual Studio 2019 and, as you can see at the benchmark comparison link, the same error that you encountered been occurred in the method of the Stack Exchange library while it hasn't been in the TheUniversalCity one.

Also, you can have a look at [the source codes of `TheUniversalCity.Redis` client library](https://github.com/TheUniversalCity/RedisClient).

Comment: This library doesn't seem to have much traction, and you were the last person to contribute to it. Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content. At minimum, you need to disclose any affiliations. As is, this reads as someone using an answer to promote a library they're involved with or, at least, have some relationship to.